# Smallest lexographic string

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to solve the following challenge:

> You are given a special string *S* and this string represents
> relations. String *S* consists of only two characters "<" and ">". Your
> task is to find the lexicographically-smallest string *L* consisting of
> unique characters of lower case Latin letters (a-z) and which follows the
> relations mentioned in *S*.
>
> For example, if you are given *S* as "<><", then
> you have to find a lexicographically-smallest string in which every
> two consecutive characters follow the relation in the order mentioned
> in *S*. Here, the answer is "acbd" as a < c > b < d.
>
> It is clear that, if *S*
> is of length *n*, then the length of *L* is *n*+1. You have to print string
> *L*.
>
> #### Input format
>
> - The first line contains *T* denoting the number of test
>   cases in each test file.
> - The first line of each test case contains
>   string *S* denoting the relations.

Comment: Could you edit your question (use the link), and add what you have tried, and where you are stuck. This looks too much like a copy/paste of a challenge, and shows no research, no effort, no code, ...

Answer (score 2):

Some observations:

- We can extend *S* with one additional "<", so to make the number of characters in *S* equal to the expected size of the output.
- If the i<sup>th</sup> character in *S* is a "<", then the corresponding output letter should be the i<sup>th</sup> letter from the alphabet.
- The group of output letters that correspond to a consecutive group of ">" in S, is the group of letters you would get if they were a sequence of "<", but then in reverse order.

With these principles in mind, it is straightforward to design the algorithm. In case a ">" is encountered, you just search for how many of those you have in a consecutive series, and produce the reversed block of letters for it. For a "<" character just output the corresponding letter from the alphabet, based on the current index.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript where you can input *S*, and the output will be displayed in real time:

```js
function minString(s) {
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    let res = "";
    s += "<"; // add a stub 
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] === "<") {
            res += letters[i];
        } else {
            let start = i;
            while (s[i] === ">") i++;
            for (let j = i; j >= start; j--) {
                res += letters[j]; // descending series of letters
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

// I/O handling

let input = document.querySelector("input");
let output = document.querySelector("div");
const refresh = () => output.textContent = minString(input.value);
input.addEventListener("input", refresh);
refresh();
```

```css
input { width:100% }
```

```html
S: <input value="&lt;&lt;>>">
Output:
<div>
```

Comment: Could you please give your comments on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
string solve(string S) {
   stack<char> st;
   string ans;
   for (int i = 0; i <= S.size(); i++) {
      st.push(i + 'a');

   if(i == S.size() || S[i] == '<') {
   while(!st.empty()) {
     ans+=st.top();
     st.pop();
   }
  }
 }
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: A code dump with no explanation is not a good answer. Can you improve your answer so it's more useful?